# how to replace gutters without disturbing roof shingles

Tags: gutters, flashing, shingles

I want to replace a 35-foot straight length of box-style metal gutter that is up against a wood fascia. My idea is to use power sheet metal shears (nibbler) and slice off the old gutter on the back side. The back is in really good shape for the full length. This would in effect leave a long piece of flashing as a drip edge. I would slide the new gutter (wingless) up underneath the now existing drip edge. My goal is to avoid disturbing the composition shingles that are in decent shape, but I don't want to mess with them. Any problems with this plan?

Comment: How will it be held, once slid into place?

Comment: @Ecnerwal Existing gutter has wings and is slipped under the shingles, held up with some spaced out gutter hangers plus screws through the back of the gutter into the studs. I'm thinking I will take out the screws so I can slip the gutter underneath the old back and then replace the screws. I'm also thinking that I can reuse the old gutter hangers. Not sure if that will be possible. Otherwise, I would use a different style hanger that screws into the fascia but doesn't slide und the shingles. The winged gutter had no slope, but with this method I can slope the gutter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I did it worked but was sort of pain, even with a power nibbler. If I did it again, I would just pull out all of the old gutter and trash it. I'd put up wingless fascia gutter which is easy to slope since there is no wing and easy to install since it can be tacked up to studs or fascia. Then slip in a piece of flashing under the shingles that extends down into the new gutter. Maybe that's obvious, but it wasn't to me when I started! The advantages are that the shingles don't have to be disturbed and it's easy to slope!

Comment: Glad you got it worked out. TBH, I have no idea what a "winged" or "wingless" gutter is. Not terms I'm familiar with. Usually, gutters are just held up with nails or screws and removing/replacing them _shouldn't_ disturb the roofing in any way. But... you've got it sorted.

Comment: the wing is just extra metal at the top of the gutter that slides up under the shingles. I think that sometimes it's nailed to the roof. I thought mine were nailed to the roof but I was wrong! https://images.homedepot-static.com/productImages/058f0679-12ef-4bca-80c8-2e1fec659d88/svn/construction-metals-gutters-fg2410wwb-64_1000.jpg